# ASP.NET MVC - Validation messages not appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

All of these fields are given the required property in the model. But when left blank and the submit button is pressed, there is no validation message appearing.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <br />

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <h2 style="text-align: center;">@ViewBag.Title</h2>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="account-wall">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #b3b3b3;">Login to your account</h3>


                    <div class="form-signin">

                        @*Email*@
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Email) })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        @*Password*@
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Password) })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        @*Submit*@
                        <div class="centered">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success " typeof="submit">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <a href="@Url.Action("Register", "Account")"><span>Register</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You don't have any submit button (it needs to be `type="submit"`)

Comment: Yes that was my problem, I thought if I gave the button a typeof="submit" it would work the same as a submit but I never thought this was the source of the problem, thanks very much.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876602/what-does-the-html-typeof-attribute-do) for an explanation of the `typeof` attribute

Comment: Check the app settings keys    `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />` and 
    `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />`. Are they set to `true`?